# Getting the average of values in an arraylist from user input.--out of bounds error

Tags: java

The project is to utilize a for-loop to read ten floating-point grades from user input. Ask the user to enter the values, then print the average, minimum, and maximum grades.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    
    public class gradeStats {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList <Double> grades = new ArrayList<Double>();
            double avgGrade = 0;
            double maxGrade = 0;
            double minGrade = 0;
            int i;
            double sum = 0;
            
            System.out.println("Enter each grade: ");
            while(scnr.hasNextDouble()) {
                grades.add(scnr.nextDouble());
            }
            scnr.close();
            System.out.println(grades);
            
            for (i=1; i < 11; ++i) {
                sum += grades.get(i);
                avgGrade = (sum / 10);
                maxGrade = Collections.max(grades);
                minGrade = Collections.min(grades);
            }
                System.out.println(grades);
                System.out.println("Maximum grade: " + maxGrade);
                System.out.println("Minimum grade: " + minGrade);
                System.out.println("Average grade: " + avgGrade);
        }
    }
```

I am able to input the grades but am getting this error:

```java
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9 out of bounds for length 9
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at gradeStats.main(gradeStats.java:27)
```

I think it's related to my grades.get(i) statement, but when I just put in sum += i, it just seems to be adding the index, i.e. 1,2,3, then dividing by 10 and so not giving me the average of the grades. Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Java arrays start at index zero and you are assuming your list of doubles is a specific length.  The loop should be `for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); ++i)`.  Also shouldn't the division to calculate the average be done **after** you've added all the values, i.e. outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear that you need a `List` of `grades` for this assignment. You seem to have forgotten you were only supposed to use a `for` loop to read ten grades (you used a `while` loop to read an indeterminate number). You can keep a running `total` in that loop (as well as `min` and `max`). Something like,

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Double> grades = new ArrayList<>();
double total = 0, min = Double.MAX_VALUE, max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter grade %02d:%n", i + 1);
    double v = scnr.nextDouble();
    min = Math.min(min, v);
    max = Math.max(max, v);
    grades.add(v);
    total += v;
}
System.out.printf("For %s: the minimum is %.2f, the maximum " //
        + "is %.2f and the average is %.2f%n", //
        grades, min, max, total / 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you have hard-coded values:

```java
for (i=1; i < 11; ++i) {
            sum += grades.get(i);
```

which is probably not what you want, since not only do you *ignore* the first grade (remember, arrays and lists in Java are *0*-indexed, so `get(0)` would return the first element, if there is one). In addition, you haven't said what the input to the program was, but judging by the exception you got, you input something like:

`81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89` (i.e. 9 values, the exact value is of no consequence).

This would then have the following effect:

`grades.get(1) == 82` (i.e. the *second* element, since Java is *0*-indexed)

`grades.get(2) == 83`

...

`grades.get(8) == 89` (the *ninth* element, again due to *0*-based indexing)

`grades.get(9) => IndexOutOfBoundsExcepion` (due to grades only containing 9 elements, and trying to get the *tenth*)

What you probably wanted it something like:

```java
for (i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++)
```

which would loop and get all the provided grades. If you specifically require **11** to be provided, you should verify that this is the case and e.g. throw an exception otherwise. I'll leave it as an exercise to you as to how to do that.